# Building list of IDs from a DataGridView ID column as an array of integers for a PostgreSQL db query filter

Tags: c#, arrays, postgresql, datagridview, npgsql

In a C# WinForms project that connects to a PostgreSQL database using the Npgsql framework, I'm iterating through a DGV's DataTable and getting record IDs for rows that have a cell that matches a search string.

Here's the code that's doing that:

```
string searchText = txtSearchCatsGrid.Text.ToUpper();
int[] idArray = new int[] { };

DataTable dt = ((DataTable)dgvCategories.DataSource);
string cellValue;
int rowIndex;
int columnIndex;
int arrayIndex = 0;

for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; rowIndex++)
{
    for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; columnIndex++)
    {
        cellValue = dt.Rows[rowIndex][columnIndex].ToString();

        if (searchText == cellValue.ToUpper())
        {
            idArray[arrayIndex] = dt.Rows[rowIndex][0];
            arrayIndex++;
        }
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idToAddToList) && !tempIdList.Contains(idToAddToList)) tempIdList += idToAddToList + ",";

}
```

I need to pass an array of integers (the list of record IDs) to a function that queries the PostgreSQL database, using that list as a filter in the WHERE clause.

My problem is, I can't figure out how to add the IDs to the array, `idArray`.

As the code is now, `dt.Rows[rowIndex][0]` has a red squiggly underline, saying "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int' (Are you missing a cast?)"

The "Are you missing a cast" prompted me to try to cast `dt.Rows[rowIndex][0]` to int using `(int)dt.Rows[rowIndex][0]`, which compiled and ran, but when I run that I get an "Index out of range" exception at `(int)dt.Rows[rowIndex][0]` when I step past that (using F11). Though arrays are zero-based, I tried initializing arrayIndex as 1, but I got the same "Index out of range" exception.

I can't use a list<>, as PostgreSQL/Npgsql can't work with that.

Comment: You must be getting the range error on `idArray[arrayIndex]`, not on `dt.Rows[rowIndex][0];`.  `dt.Rows[rowIndex][0];` must succeed, because `dt.Rows[rowIndex][columnIndex]` already succeeded before that with a `columnIndex` of zero.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Okay - I understand what you're saying, but the underline is under the `dt` part, so I assumed that was the offending part of the code. Regardless, how do I properly accomplish this? Am I not adding to the array correctly?

Comment: You didn't specify an initial size for your array here: `int[] idArray = new int[] { };`  That declares an array with zero elements.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I get that, but since I'm iterating through the DataTable and only adding to the array when a row matches, I don't know what the size of the array will be when it is initialized. What's the correct way to do that?

Comment: Use a `List<T>`, and then [convert it to an array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.toarray?view=netframework-4.8) when you're done building the list.